# How to read and merge two CSV files

Tags: python

Given 2 csv files as below:

#### file 1:

```
S.No,  Fruit , Color , Requirement
1,     Apple , Green , Not Required: in june
2,    Grapes , Black , Required
```

#### file 2 :

```
S.No,  Fruit ,  Color , Requirement
1,     Banana , Green , Not Required: in august
2,     Grapes , Black,  Required
```

I want to merge these two files and get only the `"Not required"` list.
My output should be as below:

```
S.No, Fruit ,  Color , Requirement
1,    Apple ,  Green , Not Required: in june 
2,    Banana , Green , Not Required: in august
```

I have tried the code snippet below:

```
import csv
input_files = ['fruit1.csv', 'fruit2.csv']
output_file = 'output.csv'
with open('fruit1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if "Not" in row[2]:
            print(row)
```

Comment: By 'table' I take it you mean 'File'. Also, it is unclear where the 'Not Required in june Banana' and 'Not Required in august' in your requires output come from.

Comment: @Bart Barnard,, i edited the content . hope you can understand now

Comment: Hi -- could you use some code formatting blocks to format your code and the file examples. Here's a guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_files= ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
output_file = 'output.csv'

with open('output.csv','w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['S.No', 'Fruit', 'Color', 'Requirement'])
    for file in input_files:
        with open(file,'r', newline='') as f1:
            reader = csv.reader(f1)
            new_data = [row for row in reader if 'Not' in row[3]]
            writer.writerows( new_data)

with open('output.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
import csv

input_files= ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv']
output_file = 'output.csv'

for file in input_files:
    with open(file,'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        new_data = [row for row in reader if row != [] and 'Not' in row[3]]

with open(output_file,'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['S.No', 'Fruit', 'Color', 'Requirement'])
    for index, row in enumerate(new_data):
        writer.writerow([index+1]+row[1:])
```

Comment: Am getting below error on the code : What can be the reason. Am having string value in the csv file. #new_data = [row for row in reader if 'Not' in row[3]]
#IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I assumed your csv files have 4 columns (`'S.No', 'Fruit', 'Color', 'Requirement'`) as per the sample csv you shared.. If there are 3 colums then you can change this to `new_data = [row for row in reader if 'Not' in row[2]]`

Comment: Yes my CSV file having 4 columns. I just check i could see some empty value inbetween, so in the loop it shows error index out of range

Comment: One more thing is , the filter result from the second file is replacing the output from the first file.  i.e am getting only S.No 2 in the ouput instead of 2 line. But with the filter loop both files got processed. But in the write statement , it is getting replace

Comment: No its not replacing any line..I've edited the code little bit, it should work now..

Comment: i changed the code little bit and it worked.(Posted the answer below). Thank you so much for the guidelines

Comment: You could also just do it in two command lines: `head -1 file1.csv > output.csv; grep -h 'Not Required' *.csv >> output.csv`.